# XCode can't build my project because it says my Apple ID session is expired but I can't login?

Tags: swift, xcode

So it says my session has expired, I try to login, but nothing happens... It's not like it's wrong or something if I type just one character it says "Wrong password" but if I type the correct password literally nothing happens and I can't continue building my project because of this, does anyone know what I can do? I tried to find other people with this problem but nobody seemed to have a problem where they couldn't login to their Apple ID recently.

[image: Picture]

Comment: Can you log in to your Apple ID on developer.apple.com? Did you try restarting Xcode and your Mac?

Comment: I can login on developer.apple.com and I have already restarted XCode multiple times and my mac as well but I still can't login when I'm in XCode.. I tried to remove the user and add a new one but once I put in my login details it says: "Your session has expired. Please log in." "Try signing in again or contact Apple Dev Support to resolve account access issues."

Comment: I'm gonna try calling Apple soon(they're not open yet from what I can see on the Apple dev website) but I was just curious if anyone maybe had any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Go to Xcode preferences, and open it. 2 - Then press on manage certificates on your main account. 3 - Finally press on the add icon (on the bottom left), and choose (Apple Development).

Your Certificates only need to be updated

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a fix: I added a new Apple ID to my accounts in preferences, then I deleted that account and tried to add my actual one, it asked for two step verification and then my account successfully got added.